# Conveying 'no bullshit'

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, argot, science

How would be conveyed in French 'no bullshit' in a title of a document/book as for example:

https://minireference.com/

> No bullshit guide to learn Mathematics

> 100% bullshit-free textbooks on high school math, vectors, calculus, mechanics, and linear algebra.

I am thinking about

> Apprendre les maths sans de conneries

but I am feeling this is not the proper sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Sans de conneries* is not correct: there is no partitive article after "sans", so for the grammar, it should be *sans conneries*.

Yet, *sans conneries* is not a clear phrase in French, and I feel that the word *connerie* is stronger and more vulgar than the English *bullshit*, and does not always convey the same meaning (it derives from the word *con* , which evokes the female genitalia, and is clearly an insult. A *connerie* is something very stupid (something *con*) said or done by someone, who could themselves turn out to be a *con* then).

If one was talking, a phrasing could be *sans dire de conneries*, but that is inadequate for a written document.

If by *no bullshit*, you mean that the guide gets straight to the point and does not distract readers with digressions, sidenotes, irrelevant input etc., you could use *sans blabla* in the title, which keeps a colloquial tone. See an example [here](https://www.decitre.fr/livres/la-cuisine-sans-bla-bla-9782035995551.html).

More standard phrases are *(aller) droit au but* or, a bit more elegant, *sans fioritures*.

Comment: +1, it might be difficult to compare exactly "how vulgar" two words from different languages/cultures are. The word "bullshit" is usually censored on public radio in the US, for example, whereas Le Dîner de Cons was a mainstream French movie.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

- Guide d'apprentissage des mathématiques sans détours ;

- Guide d'apprentissage des mathématiques sans fioritures (Already
  mentioned by user Greg) ;
- Guide d'apprentissage des mathématiques sans blabla (idem)
- Guide sans bullshit pour apprendre les mathématiques (I am kidding:-)!)